# Measuring code coverage in Delphi

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, code-coverage, dunit

Is there any way to measure code coverage with DUnit? Or are there any free tools accomplishing that? What do you use for that? What code coverage do you usually go for?

Jim McKeeth: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am talking about unit testing in the sense of a TDD approach, not only about unit tests after a failure occured. I'm interested in the code coverage I can achieve with some basic prewritten unit tests.

Comment: I have not accepted one of the answers yet, because I want to encourage people to write their opinion about unit testing, what tools they use and what coverage they try to achieve. So everybody, feel free to comment ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have just created a new open source project on Google Code with a basic code coverage tool for Delphi 2010.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphicodecoverage/

Right now it can measure line coverage but I'm planning to add class and method coverage too.

It generates html reports with a summary as well as marked up source showing you what lines are covered (green), which were not (red) and the rest of the lines that didn't have any code generated for them.

**Update:**
As of version 0.3 of [Delphi Code Coverage](https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphicodecoverage/) you can generate XML reports compatible with the Hudson EMMA plugin to display code coverage trends within [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

**Update:**
Version 0.5 brings bug fixes, increased configurability and cleaned up reports

**Update:**
Version 1.0 brings support for emma output, coverage of classes and methods and coverage of DLLs and BPLs

Comment: Very simple and efficient tool.
Thx for sharing !

Comment: Just a word or two of support for Christer, this tool is already useful and getting to be REALLY useful.

Comment: I've created a small wizard to help with delphi-code-coverage command line. See http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage-wizard/

Comment: also see https://github.com/MHumm/delphi-code-coverage-wizard-plus

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of any free tools.  [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp) is almost the defacto standard for profiling Delphi.  I haven't used it, but a quick search found [Discover for Delphi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/discoverd/), which is now open source, but just does code coverage.

Either of these tools should give you an idea of how much code coverage your unit tests are getting.

Comment: Discover for Delphi is now open source https://sourceforge.net/projects/discoverd/

Answer (score 7):

Are you referring to code coverage from unit tests or stale code?  Generally I think only testable code that has a failure should be covered with a unit test (yes I realize that may be starting a holy war, but that is where I stand).  So that would be a pretty low percentage.

Now stale code on the other hand is a different story.  Stale code is code that doesn't get used.  You most likely don't need a tool to tell you this for a lot of your code, just look for the little Blue Dots after you compile in Delphi.  Anything without a blue dot is stale.  Generally if code is not being used then it should be removed.  So that would be 100% code coverage.

There are other scenarios for stale code, like if you have special code to handle if the date ever lands on the 31st of February.  The compiler doesn't know it can't happen, so it compiles it in and gives it a blue dot.  Now you can write a unit test for that, and test it and it might work, but then you just wasted your time a second time (first for writing the code, second for testing it).

There are tools to track what code paths get used when the program runs, but that is only simi-reliable since not all code paths will get used every time.  Like that special code you have to handle leap year, it will only run every four years.  So if you take it out then your program will be broken every four years.

I guess I didn't really answer your question about DUnit and Code Coverage, but I think I may have left you with more questions then you started with.  What kind of code coverage are you looking for?

**UPDATE:**  If you are taking a TDD approach then no code is written until you write a test for it, so by nature you have 100 test coverage.  Of course just because each method is exercised by a test does not mean that its entire range of behaviors is exercised.  [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/) provides a really easy method to measure which methods are called along with timing, etc.  It is a little less then AQTime, but not free.  With some more work on your part you can add instrumentation to measure every code path (branches of "if" statements, etc.)  Of course you can also just add your own logging to your methods to achieve a coverage report, and that is free (well, expect for your time, which is probably worth more then the tools).  If you use JEDI Debug then you can get a call stack too.

TDD really cannot easily be applied retroactively to existing code without a lot of refactoring.  Although the newer Delphi IDEs have the ability to generate unit test stubs for each public method, which then gives you 100% coverage of your public methods.  What you put in those stubs determines how effective that coverage is.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to make it more clear what I mean.

Comment: I added some more to cover TDD.

Comment: "...but that is only simi-reliable ... your program will be broken every four years." That is were unit tests on code that (currently) has no failures might help in preventing the code being deleted when the code coverage is run only on non-leap years? :) Personally I think any functions dealing with dates should be exercised in unit tests with all kinds of ivvy dates passed into them. Same applies to any "basic" functions that deal with "environmental factors". You do not want to be dependent on the current machine setup/date for your test /coverage results.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Discover for Delphi](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/discoverd/) and it does the work, for unit testing with DUnit and Functional testing with TestComplete.

Discover can be configured to run from the command line for automation.
As in:

```
Discover.exe Project.dpr -s -c -m
```

Answer (score 2):

Discover works great for me. It hardly slows down your application, unlike AQTime. This may not be a problem for you anyway, of course. I think the recent versions of AQTime perform better in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Discover" for years, worked excellently up to and including BDS2006 (which was the last pre-XE* version of Delphi i used and still use), but its current opensourced state, it's unclear how to make it work with XE* versions of Delphi. A shame really, because I loved this tool, fast and convenient in almost every way.
So now I'm moving to delphi-code-coverage...