# Is there any way to omit some lines from Delphi-code-coverage measurement?

Tags: delphi, code-coverage, delphi-xe3

I am covering my project with unit tests, and there are some lines which obviously will never be reached. E.g.:

```
constructor TSomeClass.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;
    raise ENotSupportedException.Create('This class does not support parameterless Create') at ReturnAddress;
end;//<- this line generates code but is unreachable
```

To measure coverage I am using [Delphi-code-coverage](https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphicodecoverage/)

As far as I googled, and browsed its code I found no way to mark this `end;` as one which cannot be covered.

So, is there any way to mark such lines?

Comment: Just a link to a delphi code-coverage answer here at SO: [Measuring code coverage in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115701/576719)

Comment: @LURD: I didn't catch what is your comment about. My question is about the usage of the tool, already selected, not about which tool should I select.

Comment: Yes I know, I just provided a cross-reference link.

Comment: Just a stupid idea - Assuming that the "Delphi Code Coverage" tool uses the blue breakpoint lines, your `Error(..)` method could be non-public and marked with the `inline` directive. That effectively removes the blue breakpoints.

Comment: Or you could redesign the code so that the `Error` method returns the exception rather than raising it directly. Not always what you want though.

Comment: @HonzaR: Well, real code is in the constructor (I have updated the question), so returning the exception is not an option.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful:  Well, real code is in the constructor (I have updated the question), so I cannot make it neither `inline` nor `private`

Comment: In that case, I would throw a `System.SysUtils.ENoConstructException` which seems to be made for stuff like this. Not answering the question, but still wanted to mention it.

Comment: See [How to hide the inherited TObject constructor while the class has overloaded ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14003153/576719). There are solutions that will make the `TSomeClass.Create` obsolete.